# How to close Gnu process?

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I'm trying to make a script using Perl and the
[`Chart::Gnuplot`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Chart::Gnuplot)
module for Linux to represent a series of data. It is something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Chart::Gnuplot;

die "Linux check" if ( $^O ne 'linux' );

my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
    terminal => 'x11',
    title    => {
        text => "GRAPH",
        font => "Arial, 20"
    },
    xlabel => {
        text  => "X AXIS",
        font   => "arial, 20",
        offset =>"0,-1"
    },
    ylabel => {
        text   => "Y AXIS",
        font   => "arial, 20",
        offset =>"-6,0"
    },
);

my $dataSet = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    xdata => \@x_data,
    ydata => \@y_data,
    style => "points",
);

$chart->plot2d($dataSet);

exit;
```

When I run this from Eclipse, the script works OK and the graph shows correctly, but the process won't terminate (closing the Gnuplot window won't work). Something similar happens when I run it at the terminal.

The problematic line is  `$chart->plot2d($dataSet)` without which it can terminate correctly. What could I do to end it right after closing the window?

Comment: [gnuplot exit on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063622/gnuplot-exit-on-window-close) may be related

Comment: It seems like the `plot2d()` command is waiting for an EOF character. Try press CTRL-D in the terminal window.

Comment: I think the reason it waits for commands in the terminal after plotting  is that you specified the `terminal => 'x11'` option. If you remove that option and specify `output => "test.png"` instead, it will save to a file instead and not wait in the terminal for further commands

Comment: Thanks, both worked, but I wanted the script to be as clean as possible (I didn't want to press CTRL-D every time) and the option to use mouse interactions, so the .png output wasn't enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Chart::Gnuplot` runs `gnuplot` with the same stdin and other file descriptors open. After drawing the picture, `gnuplot` reads stdin waiting for more commands.

One solution is to simply redirect stdin to `/dev/null` in your perl program before doing the plot. This will also make the image immediately appear and disappear, so you should also add the `persist` option. Here are the 2 lines to change:

```
my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
    terminal => 'x11 persist',
...
open(STDIN, "<", "/dev/null") or die "Can't open /dev/null: $!";
$chart->plot2d($dataSet);
```

Comment: Closing `STDIN` (or any other standard handle (`STDOUT`, `STDERR`)) is a very, very bad idea. The next file that gets opened (maybe implicitly 15 levels down the call stack in some module) gets file descriptor 0, and anyone reading from `STDIN` will see "interesting" input. Much better: `open STDIN, "<", "/dev/null" or die "Can't open /dev/null: $!";` i.e. redirect stdin to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Thank you both! This worked exactly as I wanted, now the script ends without waiting for a command